# Alternate/better way of prepending an element using Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have a collection of lines, like in this snippet:

```
  def insertBeforeLine(text:String,whichLine:String,what:String) = {
    val lines = text.lines
    lines.foldLeft(ListBuffer[String]())((acumulator,element) => {
       acumulator ++ { if(element == whichLine) Array(what,element) else Array(element) }
    }).mkString("\n")
  }
```

I am trying to prepend something before every line that's equal to `whichLine`. Is there a better/cleaner way? For example if my input is:

```
line1
line2
line4
```

and I call my function like `insertBeforeLine(input,"line4","line3")` it will produce:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really have a string of lines (and you can include the end-of-line character, and it's consistent), you can use replace from `java.lang.String`:

```
text.replace(which,what+which)
```

but if you want something more general, something like

```
lines.flatMap(l => if (l==which) Seq(what,l) else Seq(l))
```

is a compact and clear way to express it (at least to those who know how `flatMap` works).

If you want something maximally efficient, then it's a long ugly answer with lots of while loops and probably some byte array intermediates.